# how to stop line wrapping in verilog output from Synopsys Design Compiler

Tags: verilog

I'm getting line wrapping in the gate-level verilog file output from Design Compiler.
This is causing problems for Cadence verilog-in.

This seems like it would be easy to stop in Design Compiler, but I don't
see any control switches for the "write_file" command, when I do
"man write_file" in Design Compiler.

So I searched the 2014 Design Compiler User Guide, and did not find anything about
controlling line wrapping. And a Google search did not find anything.

Is there an "attribute" or command that I can set inside DC that controls
line-wrapping on hdl writes ? Note, I can fix this with a perl script,
but prefer to fix this at the source.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think you have any choice other than post-processing the output Verilog netlist. But take into account that Cadence should be able to process the netlist independently of the wrapping format as long as the Verilog code is correct.